# SIM808 emits random numbers

Tags: at-commands, sim

I am programing a Maduino M0 board with a [SIM808](https://www.simcom.com/product/SIM808.html) GSM/GPRS/GPS module on it using the Arduino IDE. Periodically, after reprogramming the board a few times, the SIM808 no longer responds to any serial requests and simply outputs a long string of numbers.

```
07:08:37.906 -> SIM808:AT:SENT
07:08:37.906 -> 658413131079751310 SIM808:AT:ERROR
07:08:42.912 -> SIM808:AT:SENT
07:08:42.912 -> 658413131079751310 SIM808:AT:ERROR
07:08:47.906 -> SIM808:AT:SENT
07:08:47.906 -> 658413131079751310 SIM808:AT:ERROR
07:08:52.904 -> SIM808:AT:SENT
07:08:52.904 -> 658413131079751310 SIM808:AT:ERROR
07:08:57.865 -> SIM808:AT:SENT
07:08:57.865 -> 658413131079751310 SIM808:AT:ERROR
07:09:02.911 -> SIM808:AT:SENT
07:09:02.911 -> 658413131079751310 SIM808:AT:ERROR
07:09:07.870 -> SIM808:AT:SENT
07:09:07.870 -> 658413131079751310 SIM808:AT:ERROR
```

If I restart the board and reprogram it with one of the demo scripts, then compile and upload my own program, then the serial port starts working again. I don't mind this but it makes me wonder how I might reliably ensure my program (re)starts the SIM808 properly.

My program is as follows :

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <RTCZero.h>  // RTCZero
#include "Mobile.h"   // Mobile subclasses of ManagedSerialDevice
#include "Vaisala.h"  // Vaisala subclasses of ManagedSerialDevice

// Environment
// ===========
#define DEBUG true  //true: debug on; false:debug off; set to off for field devices.

// SIM808
// -------
int  SIM808_PWR =     9; // D9:     SIM 808 Power pin
int  SIM808_SLP =     5; // D5:     SIM 808 Sleep/Low Power TODO: Confirm This
bool SIM808_STS = false; // Status: SIM 808 Power status 
bool SIM808_TRX =     0; // D0:     SIM 808 Serial Rx
bool SIM808_RCV =     1; // D1:     SIM 808 Serial Tx

// Date and Time
// =============
const byte year    = 0;
const byte month   = 0;
const byte day     = 0;
const byte hours   = 0;
const byte minutes = 0;
const byte seconds = 0;
RTCZero rtc;

//// Message Passing
//// ---------------
String strMessage = "";    // String containing a serial message

// Serial 1: SIM808
// ----------------
SIM808 MOBILE = SIM808(); // ManagedSerialDevice subclass

void setup() {
  // Date Time
  // =========
  rtc.begin();
  rtc.setYear(year);
  rtc.setMonth(month);
  rtc.setDay(day);
  rtc.setHours(hours);
  rtc.setMinutes(minutes);
  rtc.setSeconds(seconds);

  // CYCLE: SIM808
  // -------------
  pinMode(SIM808_PWR, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(SIM808_PWR, LOW); // Enable output keep low
  pinMode(SIM808_SLP, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(SIM808_SLP, LOW); // Enable output keep low
  delay(1100);
  digitalWrite(SIM808_PWR, HIGH);
  delay(1000); // Turn On
  //digitalWrite(SIM808_PWR, LOW);
  //delay(3000); // Turn Off
  digitalWrite(SIM808_PWR, LOW);                // Standby
  //COPIED: Restart seen in other codee
  //if (!SIM808_PWR) {
  //  digitalWrite(SIM808_PWR, LOW);
  //  delay(3000); // Turn Off
  //  digitalWrite(SIM808_PWR, HIGH);
  //  delay(1000); // Turn On
  //  if (DEBUG) {
  //    SerialUSB.println("SIM808:POWER:RES");
  //  }
  //}
  // Serial: USB
  // -----------
  SerialUSB.begin(9600);
  while (!SerialUSB) {
    delay(100);
  }
  // Serial: SIM808
  // --------------  
  Serial1.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial1) {
    delay(100);
  }
  strMessage = Serial1.readString();
  SerialUSB.print(strMessage);
  if (DEBUG) {
    MOBILE.begin(&Serial1, &SerialUSB);
  } else {
    MOBILE.begin(&Serial1);
  }
  // Initialization
  // --------------
  if (DEBUG) {
    SerialUSB.println("INITIALIZED");
  }
  // Serial: Flush
  // -------------
  delay(2500);
  while (Serial1.available() > 0) {
    strMessage = Serial1.read(); 
    if (DEBUG) {
      SerialUSB.print(strMessage);
    }
    yield();
  }
  while (SerialUSB.available() > 0) {
    if (DEBUG) {
      Serial1.write(SerialUSB.read());
    }
    yield();
  }    
  delay(2500);
  if (DEBUG) {
    SerialUSB.println("SERIAL:FLUSHED");
  }
}

void loop() {
  MOBILE.atAT();
  // Serial: Flush
  // -------------
  while (Serial1.available() > 0) {
    strMessage = Serial1.read(); 
    if (DEBUG) { SerialUSB.print(strMessage); }
      yield();
    }
  while (SerialUSB.available() > 0) {
    if (DEBUG) { Serial1.write(SerialUSB.read()); }
      yield();
    }    
  MOBILE.loop();
  delay(5000);
}
```

`SIM808`, above, is a subclass of `ManagedSerialDevice` which extends the original class to support the `atAT` method; which simply executes the `AT` command.

```
bool SIM808::atAT()
/*
 * AT(tention)
 * 
 * Check device has started up
 */
{
//  static bool result;
  SIM808::execute(
    "AT",
    "OK\r\n",
    [this] (MatchState match) -> void {
//      char echo[3] = "";         // \0 terminated string of length 1
//      match.GetCapture(echo, 0); // \0 terminated string of length 9; "[\r\nAT]\r\nOK"
      SIM808::emitMessage("SIM808:AT:OK");
//      if (DEBUG_SIM808) {
//        Serial.println("MOBILE: AT+OK!");
//        if (sizeof(echo) > 0) {
//          Serial.print("MOBILE:");
//          Serial.println(echo);
//        }
//      }
//      result = true;
    },
    [this] (ManagedSerialDevice::Command* cmd) -> void {  // Run this function on failure
      SIM808::emitMessage("SIM808:AT:ERROR");
//      if (DEBUG_SIM808) {Serial.println("MOBILE: AT ERROR!");}
//       handler.execute(cmd, ManagedSerialDevice::Timing::NEXT); // Retry the command imediately
//      result = false;
    }
  );
  SIM808::emitMessage("SIM808:AT:SENT");
//  SIM808::loop();
//  return result;
}
```

Comment: Welcome! If it responds with 658413131079751310 each time, it’s not random.

Comment: Is that the IMEI or something?

Comment: @winny True, Though there has been the odd occasion where it has responded with something longer with yet more digits.

Comment: @pjc50 I'm not entirely sure to be honest, I'm still trying to read various numbers off of the chip and am working out what number is which still.

Comment: @pjc50 It's not the IMEI  or similar number. It's certainly outputting the same string consistently on occasion it spits out this longer variant `65841313107975131013108377833282101971001211310`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using a couple of examples I had seen on the manufacturer pages. Essentially I check whether or not I'm getting a sensible response to an `AT` request. If there is no `OK` in the response then I cycle the power pin and check again. This seems to reliably restart the chipset even if there are "random" numbers on the serial line.